# Passing complex parameters to a GET Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to pass parameters for filtering to ASP.NET Core REST API Server using `HttpClient`.

Filter contains complex data type. I used to pass data by HttpPost, but it not suitable for CRUD concept.

How can I send complex data type as json object in HttpGet request?

Comment: querystring parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by defining your own Get method 
e.g.:

```
static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(this HttpClient client, string uri, HttpContent content, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), uri)
    {
        Content = content
    };
    return await client.SendAsync(request, cancelToken);
}
```

However! It is not recommended to do so, read about it here: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

The better solution would be to convert your complex object into URL parameters